# Avoid sinkhole / malicious domains when crawling the web

Tags: curl, malware

We are trying to crawl the web with our spider (respecting robots.txt etc) . The problem we are having, is that we keep getting hit with reports at abuseat.org due to hitting malicious sites / previously hacked. For example:

[image]

All we were doing in this case - was:

`curl -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9; OurSiteName http://oursite.com) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0" --max-time 10 --connect-timeout 10 -LsI $_->{domain} | grep -i Location: | tail -1`

This all runs - but then when we hit the same IP from another domain we are checking, it eventually gets us reported as running malware from our server (which we are not - as this is the only script running on the server, and its locked down).

So my question:

1. Is there a way to block malicious domains with curl, like Chrome does when you try and visit a phishing site for example?
2. or Better yet - is there an up to date list of domains we should avoid spidering? I found a few lists yesterday and have managed to clean out 50k+ domains out of ~200 million domains, but I'm sure there must be others in there that could cause us problems again :/

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the listings are related to your crawls? - Why?

Comment: Yup 100%. All the domains that are coming up on abusedb are ones in our system. I'm trying to see if I can find a definitive list of  sinkhole domains that we should avoid, but I'm guessing there won't be one. I've found the "Google SafeBrowsing", and also https://www.apivoid.com/api/domain-reputation/ , but on 200 million domains its gonna get very expensive very quick :/

Comment: I just came across this - https://github.com/stamparm/maltrail/#quick-start . Will give that an install and see if I can get it working to help us pick up the "bad" actor domains

Comment: You are claiming to be getting listed at abuseat.org. Is there another list than the CBL, which is, to my knowledge, exclusively listing based on mail server behaviour? How can you get on that list by using curl?

Comment: https://www.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=213.168.249.115 - this is where its coming from. We don't send any emails from this server. The domain in my screenshot is a sinkhole, and it seems that when you try and access it via curl (to get headers), it triggers a match and then if you happen to trigger that same sinkhole on another domain, eventually they ban you (so it seems). I've installed https://github.com/stamparm/maltrail/ and I can see the incoming scans going on, and outgoing - just need to work out how to trigger my system so it will block an IP based on the match

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. So not only actual mail server behaviour can get you on the list, but also trying to connect to a (former) control server address for a botnet will get you listed. - But even if you get listed there, I still fail to see the problem with that: Unless you are actually running an MX under the same address, this should not be a problem. - Not that you should not solve this issue, but I cannot see the value of the expended effort, yet. ;)

Comment: @I'mwithMonica yeah thats what I thought. We got some messages from Linode who thought the server was compromised. I've confirmed its us and we are doing it intentionally and respectfully. They are happy with that, but the issue seems to be we keep getting on the blacklist. It seems that some servers use IP rep to block you before you when they access their site? (there are quite a few sites we can't access, yet it was working ok before we had the IP blacklist - and I can run the same website off another server of the same spec just fine).